# Doctrine ORM how to save an UPDATE of my object to the database (equivalent of SQL UPDATE query)

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm new to Doctrine and I can't seem to find an answer to this.

To save a newly created object to the database (equivalent of SQL INSERT query), I'm using

```
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($category);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush($category);
```

And to delete one (equivalent of SQL DELETE query), I'm using

```
    $this->getEntityManager()->remove($category);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush($category);
```

Now, how do I save updates to my $category object to the database? I'm looking for the Doctrine equivalent of an UPDATE query.

Surely Doctrine ORM must have a simple method to do this, without having to use DQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no need for specific update query.

With doctrine you can update objects like this. Let's suppose you have category object with field name. So we will try to update it.

```
$newName = 'hello world';
$category->setName($newName);
$this->em->flush(); // without passing the object
```

This will update you entity.

*So following up from this, we have learnt, that you can update entities, by just using setters and setting new values, and after that you flush. It will handle things automatically.*

Comment: @Stanzi1791 Please accept it as correct answer, if it solved your issue :), thanks.

Comment: I can't accept it for another 7 minutes, will do so later :)